# twitter retweets api

Tags: ruby, twitter, twitter-gem

I'm using twitter gem as a library to work with twitter api.
I've noticed a weird issue with getting retweets for the tweet. Whenever I make a call I get only retweets from my mutual connections. 
So, if someone retweets my post I'll never be able to get that retweet using proper api call. However, search function might be a solution for this. But It's not suitable for all cases.

Anyone had the same problem with twitter ? Any advice or tips ?:)

Answer (score 0):

The twitter API allows for [retweets of me](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/retweets_of_me), which seems to be what you want. I haven't used the twitter gem, but that API method is listed in the [docs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/0.9.8/Twitter/Base:retweets_of_me).

Comment: It's not exactly what I need. I need that http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/retweets/:id , so I'll be able to retrieve all retweets for each post in my timeline. But, it's no working as it's documented on twitter's docs.